# Cannot enter text in HTML form's input field

Tags: html, css

I don't have much CSS debugging experience.  I created an html page at webflow, and got a corresponding css file.  But I cannot enter any text in the input field in any forms.  The html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="ie9 desktop-view not-mobile-device "><![endif]-->
<!--[if (!IE 9) | (!IE)]><!--><html lang="en" class="desktop-view not-mobile-device "><!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>[Tutorial] How to create a modal/pop-up in Webflow - Webflow Forums</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Community for Webflow Users to get Support and Inspiration">
    <meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="generator" content="Discourse 1.4.0.beta3 - https://github.com/discourse/discourse version 18f887772df5b25df33e7fb1bcf14d379bb9c624">

<link href="/testdrive.css?__ws=forum.webflow.com" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
  <div class="w-section section"></div>
  <div class="w-section"></div>
  <div class="w-section section">
    <div class="w-container container-style">
      <div class="label try-it">SIGN-IN</div>
      <div class="w-form">
        <form id="email-form-3" name="email-form-3" data-name="Email Form 3">
          <label for="name-4">Name:</label>
          <input class="w-input" id="name-4" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" data-name="Name 4">
          <label for="email-6">Email Address:</label>
          <input class="w-input" id="email-6" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" name="email" data-name="Email 6" required="required">
          <input class="w-button" type="submit" value="Submit" data-wait="Please wait...">
        </form>
        <div class="w-form-done">
          <p>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="w-form-fail">
          <p>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-container container-style">
      <div class="w-form">
        <form id="email-form-4" name="email-form-4" data-name="Email Form 4">
          <label for="name-5">Name:</label>
          <label for="email-7">Email Address:</label>
          <input class="w-input" id="email-7" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" name="email" data-name="Email 7" required="required">
          <input class="w-button" type="submit" value="Submit" data-wait="Please wait...">
        </form>
        <div class="w-form-done">
          <p>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="w-form-fail">
          <p>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="label try-it">SIGN-IN</div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-container container-style">
      <div class="label try-it">SIGN-IN</div>
      <div class="w-form">
        <form id="email-form-5" name="email-form-5" data-name="Email Form 5">
          <label for="name-5">LOCATION</label>
          <input class="w-input" id="name-5" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" data-name="Name 5">
          <label for="field">TIME</label>
          <input class="w-input" id="field" type="text" placeholder="Example Text" name="field" required="required">
          <label for="email-8">INVITEES</label>
          <input class="w-input" id="email-8" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" name="email" data-name="Email 8" required="required">
          <input class="w-button" type="submit" value="Submit" data-wait="Please wait...">
        </form>
        <div class="w-form-done">
          <p>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="w-form-fail">
          <p>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-container container-style">
      <div class="label try-it">SIGN-IN</div><a class="button" href="#">LIST USERS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="w-container container-style">
      <div class="label try-it">SIGN-IN</div><a class="button" href="#">LIST EVENTS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="w-inline-block" href="#">
    <a class="w-lightbox w-inline-block" href="#"><img class="close-modal" src="https://d3e54v103j8qbb.cloudfront.net/img/placeholder-thumb.svg">
      <script type="application/json" class="w-json">
        { "items": [] }
      </script>
    </a>
  </a>
  <div class="modal-window">
    <div class="w-widget w-widget-map" data-widget-latlng="51.511214,-0.119824" data-widget-style="roadmap" data-widget-zoom="12"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-section section"></div>
  <label>Label</label>
  <div class="w-section modal-background"></div>
</body>
```

The css properties of the input field are (copied from chrome developer tool):

```
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-user-select: text;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-bottom-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border-bottom-style: inset;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border-left-style: inset;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-right-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border-right-style: inset;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-top-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border-top-style: inset;
border-top-width: 2px;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
cursor: auto;
display: inline-block;
font-family: '.HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Regular';
font-size: 11px;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 13px;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: normal;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-left: 1px;
padding-right: 1px;
padding-top: 1px;
text-align: start;
text-indent: 0px;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
width: 125px;
word-spacing: 0px;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
```

Including inherited properties:

```
-webkit-app-region: no-drag;
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
-webkit-background-composite: source-over;
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-box-align: stretch;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: slice;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-webkit-box-flex-group: 1;
-webkit-box-lines: single;
-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: start;
-webkit-box-reflect: none;
-webkit-column-break-after: auto;
-webkit-column-break-before: auto;
-webkit-column-break-inside: auto;
-webkit-column-count: auto;
-webkit-column-gap: normal;
-webkit-column-rule-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-column-rule-style: none;
-webkit-column-rule-width: 0px;
-webkit-column-span: none;
-webkit-column-width: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
-webkit-highlight: none;
-webkit-hyphenate-character: auto;
-webkit-line-box-contain: block inline replaced;
-webkit-line-break: auto;
-webkit-line-clamp: none;
-webkit-locale: "en";
-webkit-margin-after-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-margin-before-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-mask-box-image: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-outset: 0px;
-webkit-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch;
-webkit-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill;
-webkit-mask-box-image-source: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-width: auto;
-webkit-mask-clip: border-box;
-webkit-mask-composite: source-over;
-webkit-mask-image: none;
-webkit-mask-origin: border-box;
-webkit-mask-position: 0% 0%;
-webkit-mask-repeat: repeat;
-webkit-mask-size: auto;
-webkit-print-color-adjust: economy;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-webkit-text-combine: none;
-webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none;
-webkit-text-emphasis-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-text-emphasis-position: over;
-webkit-text-emphasis-style: none;
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-text-orientation: vertical-right;
-webkit-text-security: none;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
-webkit-user-drag: auto;
-webkit-user-modify: read-only;
-webkit-user-select: text;
align-content: start;
align-items: start;
align-self: start;
alignment-baseline: auto;
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-direction: normal;
animation-duration: 0s;
animation-fill-mode: none;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-name: none;
animation-play-state: running;
animation-timing-function: ease;
backface-visibility: visible;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-blend-mode: normal;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: auto;
baseline-shift: 0px;
border-bottom-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-style: inset;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-collapse: separate;
-webkit-border-image: none;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border-left-style: inset;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-right-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border-right-style: inset;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-top-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-style: inset;
border-top-width: 2px;
bottom: auto;
box-shadow: none;
box-sizing: content-box;
buffered-rendering: auto;
caption-side: top;
clear: none;
clip: auto;
clip-path: none;
clip-rule: nonzero;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
color-interpolation: sRGB;
color-interpolation-filters: linearRGB;
color-rendering: auto;
cursor: auto;
cx: 0px;
cy: 0px;
direction: ltr;
display: inline-block;
dominant-baseline: auto;
empty-cells: show;
fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
fill-opacity: 1;
fill-rule: nonzero;
filter: none;
flex-basis: auto;
flex-direction: row;
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
float: none;
flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
flood-opacity: 1;
font-family: '.HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Regular';
font-kerning: auto;
font-size: 11px;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-weight: normal;
glyph-orientation-horizontal: 0deg;
glyph-orientation-vertical: auto;
height: 13px;
image-rendering: auto;
isolation: auto;
justify-content: start;
left: auto;
letter-spacing: normal;
lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
line-height: normal;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
marker-end: none;
marker-mid: none;
marker-start: none;
mask: none;
mask-type: luminance;
max-height: none;
max-width: none;
min-height: 0px;
min-width: 0px;
mix-blend-mode: normal;
object-fit: fill;
object-position: 50% 50%;
opacity: 1;
order: 0;
orphans: auto;
outline-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
outline-offset: 0px;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow-wrap: normal;
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: visible;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-left: 1px;
padding-right: 1px;
padding-top: 1px;
page-break-after: auto;
page-break-before: auto;
page-break-inside: auto;
paint-order: fill stroke markers;
perspective: none;
perspective-origin: 65.5px 9.5px;
pointer-events: auto;
position: static;
r: 0px;
resize: none;
right: auto;
rx: 0px;
ry: 0px;
shape-image-threshold: 0;
shape-margin: 0px;
shape-outside: none;
shape-rendering: auto;
speak: normal;
stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
stop-opacity: 1;
stroke: none;
stroke-dasharray: none;
stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
stroke-linecap: butt;
stroke-linejoin: miter;
stroke-miterlimit: 4;
stroke-opacity: 1;
stroke-width: 1px;
tab-size: 8;
table-layout: auto;
text-align: start;
text-anchor: start;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-overflow: clip;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
top: auto;
touch-action: auto;
transform: none;
transform-origin: 65.5px 9.5px;
transform-style: flat;
transition-delay: 0s;
transition-duration: 0s;
transition-property: all;
transition-timing-function: ease;
unicode-bidi: normal;
vector-effect: none;
vertical-align: baseline;
visibility: visible;
white-space: normal;
widows: 1;
width: 125px;
will-change: auto;
word-break: normal;
word-spacing: 0px;
word-wrap: normal;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
x: 0px;
y: 0px;
z-index: auto;
zoom: 1;
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Works as intended here: http://jsfiddle.net/zsnsoofk/ Checked both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Works fine [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/r8v4rufx/1)

Comment: Disable Javascript for a test, and check if that causes your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  With only the "form" it works, but in a complete HTML document, doesn't work any more.

Comment: If I put all your HTML in a file here locally, it still works. So not sure what goes wrong at your end. Apparently there are things you are not showing. Can you provide the URI of your site, or (preferably) a snippet here in the question that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: One thing I noticed is you don't have a closing html tag

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the comments.  I found the cause... After I delete this from the html:

```
<div class="w-section modal-background"></div>
```

It works.

The associated css properties are:

```
.modal-background {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```